# Why there's no checkbox of the terms and conditions in the checkout?

Tags: cart

I'm a newbie of magento :)
I wanted to ask , as ever , despite having flagged in magento admin checkbox that enables conditions and terms and , why in the frontend , in the checkout at the end of the purchase process , there's no checkbox terms and conditions ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add Terms and Conditions in the admin panel -> Sales -> Terms and Conditions -> Add New in order to display the checkbox. Also Onepage Checkout must be enabled (admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> SALES -> Checkout -> Checkout Options -> Enable Onepage Checkout : Yes).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
The strange thing is that in the sales page of the configuration , there is no terms and conditions link :(
How so? It may be because I'm using a template ?
http://i.imgur.com/566iY7y.jpg  in this image you can see that there isn't terms&conditions.
The version of my magento is 1.9.0.1

Comment: Enable/Disable Terms and Conditions is in SALES -> Checkout -> Checkout Options, not in SALES -> Sales (the screenshot that you sent is from SALES -> Sales).

Comment: Ah , but in that page I had already selected the checkbox . Equally , however , there's no checkbox in the frontend checkout page :(
image attached http://i.imgur.com/Iptf4n8.jpg

Comment: As I wrote in the answer - also you have to add Terms and Conditions in the admin panel -> Sales -> Terms and Conditions -> Add New (not in the System -> Configuration -> Sales, but in the main menu -> Sales).

Comment: Ah thanks! I hadn't figured out what you were referring page!
Now it works! Thanks and sorry for the newbie questions!
Thank you!

Comment: Accepted! Thenks!